# Remove Ukrainian flag from folium map

Tags: leaflet, folium

Is there a way to remove the Ukrainian flag at the bottom right of a map created with folium?

[image]

I am happy to mention leaflet, but having a flag is a no go and I would have to stop using folium if there is no easy workaround.
thank you

Comment: Wrong spot - you need to get the maintainers to deal with this (if it's something they need to deal with) on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues).

Comment: And then a maintainer (i.e. *me*) will kindly tell you to RTFM. https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-setprefix

Comment: Thanks both i found an alternative. @IvanSanchez the thing is that i wanted to change that in the python code for the folium map, where as far as i can tell the leaflet attribution control is not properly exposed. This can be adjusted post fact on the html directly

Answer (score 3):

It looks like folium (version 0.12.1.post1) doesn't add that flag to attributions when creating maps in Python. If you have the latest version of folium, you can simply remove it and install the version 0.12.1.post1 (maybe some slightly newer ones will work too).

In JavaScript you can try to pass attributionControl: false when creating your map, then add a new attribution control to the map, then call the setPrefix method with the Leaflet URL, and finally load tile layers on the map:

```javascript
var map = L.map('map', {attributionControl: false}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var myAttrControl = L.control.attribution().addTo(map);
myAttrControl.setPrefix('<a href="https://leafletjs.com/">Leaflet</a>');

const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: 'Data by &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/">ODbL.</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

The map will look as before, but the flag will be gone:

[image: Leaflet map without flag]